# jQuery - select inputs for specific form on page with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, loops

On my page I have multiple forms for different purposes. I want to validate just one of these forms. So I want to loop through the inputs for this form and check each of them. Problem is, when I loop through the inputs I am also seeing inputs from the other forms.

Example:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="#">
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1"/>
<input type="text" name="test2" id="test2"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="get" action="#">
<input type="text" name="test3" id="test3"/>
<input type="text" name="test4" id="test4"/>
</form>

<script>
jQuery('#form2').submit(function( event ) {
    validate_form(this);
    event.preventDefault();
});

function validate_form(form){
    jQuery(form+':input').each(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
</script>
```

Output will be:

test1
test2
test3
test4

What i want to see is:

test3
test4

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `id` of the submitted form to get your expected results.

Try,

```
jQuery('#form2').submit(function( event ) {
    validate_form($(this).attr('id'));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.find()`

```
function validate_form(form){
    jQuery(form).find(':input').each(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following jQuery code is working :

```
jQuery('#form2').submit(function( event ) {
    validate_form(this);
    event.preventDefault();
});

function validate_form(form){
    jQuery(form).children('input').each(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 jQuery('#form2').submit(function( event ) {
        validate_form($(this));
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function validate_form(form){
        jQuery(form).find(':input').each(function(){
            console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
        });
    }
```